# Magento 1.9.1 - Custom Module to update log file after checkout specific SKU product

Tags: php, module, magento-1.9, checkout, sku

I am using Magento 1.9.1 and I would like to write in a custom log file after user place an order with specific SKU product.
I followed some tutorial explain how to create module but I can't run it in any way.

First of all I created in **app/etc/modules/MyName_MyModule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyName_MyModule>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyName_MyModule>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Checked inside administration and the module it's activated correctly.
[view detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxvSe.png)

After that I created in **app/code/local/MyName/MyModule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyName_MyModule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MyName_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <local>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyName_MyModule_Model</class>
            </mymodule>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <updatelogfile>
                        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                        <method>updateLogFile</method>
                    </updatelogfile>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>
    </local>
</config>
```

and the Observer in **app/code/local/MyName/MyModule/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
class MyName_MyModule_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {

    public function updateLogFile($observer) {

        $order_ids = $observer->getData('order_ids');

        if(isset($order_ids)) {
            foreach ($order_ids as $order_id) :

            $sendToMe = false;
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
            if (isset($order)) {

                 $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
                 foreach ($orderItems as $_item) {

                     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getData('product_id'));
                     $name = $product->getName();
                     $sku = $product->getSku();
                     if($sku == ('MR002-S' || 'MR002-M' || 'MR002-L' || 'MR002-XL' || 'MR002-XXL')) { // Your SKUs
                              $sendToMe = true;
                     }

                 }
             }

             if($sendToMe) {
                 // write order data in custom log file
                 Mage::log("{$name} ({$sku}) ordered", null, 'custom_order.log');
              }

             endforeach;
        }
    }

}
```

Uploaded the custom log file named **custom_order.log** in **var/log/** and chmod 777

After that I cleared all the Magento Cache and disabled it but if I try to checkout a product with a specific $sku my log file doesn't update..

What I have to do again? It all seems so clear but I think I miss something..

Answer (score 0):

Change this file as below

```
<?php
class MyName_MyModule_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {

    public function updateLogFile($observer) {

        $order_ids = $observer->getData('order_ids');

        if(isset($order_ids)) {
            foreach ($order_ids as $order_id) :

            $sendToMe = false;
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
            if (isset($order)) {

                 $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
                 foreach ($orderItems as $_item) {

                     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getData('product_id'));
                     $name = $product->getName();
                     $sku = $product->getSku();
                     if($sku == ('MR002-S' || 'MR002-M' || 'MR002-L' || 'MR002-XL' || 'MR002-XXL')) { // Your SKUs
                              $sendToMe = true;
                              if($sendToMe) 
                               {
                                   // write order data in custom log file
                              Mage::log("{$name} ({$sku}) ordered", null, 'custom_order.log');
              }
                     }

                 }
             }



             endforeach;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Jinesh, thanks for your answer. That's correct but this not resolve the problem, I think that there is something wrong with the module..I can't figure it out

Comment: can we talk in other plaftform?